# How do I prevent imageview overlapping?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imageview, android-constraintlayout

I can't figure out how to stop this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVhXk.png) from overlapping the other two TextViews. I need the two TextViews to maintain their position and for the ImageView to be constrained between them without being cropped.

All of these views go through different visibility states (visible/invisible/gone), so I tried adding barriers, but that didn't work. I've tried changing margins, padding, constraints etc.

The top TextView is tv_question. 
The bottom TextView is tv_answer.
Between the two TextViews are two ImageViews that sit on top of each other in the layout. However, only one ImageView at a time is shown.

Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_exit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_exit"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_question"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier_question"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_question"
    app:barrierDirection="top"
    app:barrierAllowsGoneWidgets="false"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="iv_question, iv_answer" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_question"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_answer"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_question" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_answer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_answer"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_question" />

<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier_answer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_answer"
    app:barrierDirection="bottom"
    app:barrierAllowsGoneWidgets="false"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="iv_question, iv_answer"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_answer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="112dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_complete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/quiz_complete"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_showAnswer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="@string/quiz_showAnswer"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_nextQuestion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="@string/quiz_nextQuestion"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Restart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
    android:text="@string/quiz_restart"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Exit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
    android:text="@string/quiz_exit"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

Comment: can you provide us with the id of the image view and the two text view?

Comment: Added info on IDs, order etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set the height of the two Imageviews to be match_constraint

> android:layout_height="0dp"

the full code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_exit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_exit"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_question"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier_question"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_question"
    app:barrierDirection="top"
    app:barrierAllowsGoneWidgets="false"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="iv_question, iv_answer" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_question"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_answer"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_question" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_answer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_answer"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_question" />

<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier_answer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_answer"
    app:barrierDirection="bottom"
    app:barrierAllowsGoneWidgets="false"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="iv_question, iv_answer"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_answer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="112dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_complete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/quiz_complete"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_showAnswer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="@string/quiz_showAnswer"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_nextQuestion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="@string/quiz_nextQuestion"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Restart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
    android:text="@string/quiz_restart"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Exit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
    android:text="@string/quiz_exit"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Can you explain to me what I was doing wrong and why this worked?

Comment: Great! .. the height should match the constraint of the barrier you are created to be between of them.